# How to zoom the selected part of the graph using pan gesuture in coreplot ios

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, ios6.1

How can Zoom the selected part of the graph using pan gesture. At first I can see full graph when I select some part of the graph using pinch that part should occupy full.

Suggest me with ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Add a gesture recognizer to the hosting view and manipulate the graph in response to the gesture. You can turn off the default pinch scaling (`allowPinchScaling` = NO) if it gets in the way.